# Function Overloading in Julia - Keyword Argument

Tags: julia, overloading

Suppose a function `fun()` with keywords is overloaded like this:

```
function fun(; a::Real)
    return a
end

function fun(; a::Vector)
    return a
end
```

When executing the following code, I get a type error: `TypeError: in keyword argument a, expected Vector, got a value of type Int64`:

```
fun(1) # TypeError
fun([1, 2])
```

But when the function `fun()` gets normal arguments, i.e.:

```
function fun(a::Real)
    return a
end

function fun(a::Vector)
    return a
end
```

Then executing of this code snippet here:

```
fun(1) # -> 1
fun([1, 2]) # -> [1, 2]
```

works.

###### Why does the second example work, but the first does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyword arguments are not overloadable. In other words, they do not participate in method dispatch---only positional arguments participate in dispatch. When you define the second method, `f(; a::Vector)`, it overwrites the first method:

```
julia> function fun(; a::Real)
           return a
       end
fun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function fun(; a::Vector)
           return a
       end
fun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methods(fun)
# 1 method for generic function "fun":
[1] fun(; a) in Main at REPL[2]:1
```

Comment: Thanks,that answers my question. That's what I thought, but since I couldn't find any information about it I asked the question.

Comment: @fakl It"s in [the doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Note-on-Optional-and-keyword-Arguments): "Keyword arguments behave quite differently from ordinary positional arguments. In particular, they do not participate in method dispatch. Methods are dispatched based only on positional arguments, with keyword arguments processed after the matching method is identified."